# cURL to https endpoint works but openssl connect returns code: 21 unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: tls, openssl

I would like to verify that the TLS connection to given https endpoint is working fine, also would like to download the server certificate so that I can use it through java api.

So, I have an https endpoint `https://some-endpoint.net:443` **which I can cURL successfully.**

```
curl -v -XGET  -H "Authorization: Basic base64_hash" https:/some-endpoint.net/resources/roles

* Connected to some-endpoint.net (172.21.2.2) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: some-endpoint.net
* Server certificate: SomeCompany Issuing CA Sea
> GET /resources/roles HTTP/1.1
> Host: some-endpoint.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic base64_b2t
```

But `openssl s_client -connect some-endpoint.net:443` gives me `unable to verify the first certificate` message.

```
    CONNECTED(00000003)

    Server certificate
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

    -----END CERTIFICATE-----

    ---
    No client certificate CA names sent
    ---
    SSL handshake has read 1928 bytes and written 467 bytes
    ---
    New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
    Server public key is 2048 bit
    Secure Renegotiation IS supported
    Compression: NONE
    Expansion: NONE
    SSL-Session:

    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: 94E0D2ACF4557FF3A277C50B38B32664D3BC41B4AAE816C98957A4B3BD77FB8E
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: some_96_bytes_alpha_num
    Key-Arg   : None
    Start Time: 1500015432
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
    ---
    closed
```

Or with SNI `openssl s_client -connect some-endpoint.net:443 -servername some-endpoint.net:443`, its the same code: 21 error.

I don't know where macos puts certs in. `/usr/local/etc/openssl/certs/` is empty.

```
$ ll /usr/local/etc/openssl/
total 576
14172443 -rwxrwxrwx  1 prayagupd  admin  279653 Apr 13 01:10 cert.pem
  913040 drwxrwxrwx  2 prayagupd  admin      68 Nov 11  2016 certs
  913041 drwxrwxrwx  9 prayagupd  admin     306 Nov 11  2016 misc
  913049 -rwxrwxrwx  1 prayagupd  admin   10835 Apr 13 01:10 openssl.cnf
  913050 drwxrwxrwx  2 prayagupd  admin      68 Nov 11  2016 private
```

I actually came from [Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32074827/432903)
 as I can send GET requests to the endpoint but couldn't connect through java API.

So, my question is why `openssl s_client -connect some-endpoint.net:443` is failing with code 21.

Comment: While there are not enough information in your question to be sure my guess  is that the difference is between using SNI and not SNI - and thus it is marked as duplicate. If you feel that this is not the problem please show more output from `openssl s_client`, especially the certificates you get from the server compared to the ones you get with curl.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you. I will try the other answer and update the question if needed. I didn't share much info as this https endpoint is internal to an organisation.

Comment: If you're using an older non-RedHat version of OpenSSL `s_client` doesn't default the truststore as it should, see my https://superuser.com/questions/903247/ssl-root-ca-certificate-is-not-recognized-although-present-in-the-trust-store/904494#904494 . (ninja) Your config is apparently using the file cert.pem not the dir certs/; OpenSSL does both. Note this won't help with accessing from Java, which uses its own truststore(s) that can depend on your environment, libraries, and code. PS: `-servername` should NOT include `:port`.